Did anyone ever ask Neil Armstrong whether he said "for man" or "for a man?"
I should think that would certainly settle the matter.

An unsubstantiated story I heard was that the much-rehearsed line was supposed to be "by a man". Neil just blew it. Maybe he had something else on his mind at the time.

During the TV live broadcast few people likely heard or understood what Neil said at that moment. It wasn’t obvious from the shadowy TV pictures when the first step occurred. Walter Cronkite thought Neil had already stepped on the Moon and began pontificating, and came within milliseconds of stepping on Neil's statement. Wally Schirra said, “I think that was Neil’s quote but I didn’t understand it.” Cronkite, “One small step for man but I didn’t get the second phrase”. Frank McGee on NBC, “I think he said one small step for man but one giant leap for man. I’m not certain I got all that right”.

What exactly are the grammatical implications of a missing "a"? "for a man" refers to himself, I believe. "for man" would imply something like "human" or is it automatically a "for men" if the a is omitted? At least I assume there is some question about the quote being sexist lingering in the air, but I think this is absurd to assume. I also think the audio has something like "...fora man..." munched together and the pauses being because of climbing down the ladder while timing the sentence with the first step on the moon's surface.

Yes, at least one writer has asked him directly.  As mentioned in
the Apollo 11 Lunar Surface Journal:

109:24:23 Armstrong: That's one small step for (a) man; one giant leap for mankind. (Long Pause)
[At the time of the mission, the world heard Neil say "That's one small step for man; one giant leap for mankind". As Andrew Chaikin details in A Man on the Moon, after the mission, Neil said that he had intended to say 'one small step for a man' and believed that he had done so. However, he also agreed that the 'a' didn't seem to be audible in the recordings.

The A Man on the Moon reference is to a footnote on page 209 (Penguin paperback edition) and reads in full

The quote would be forever footnoted. Armstrong would report after the flight that he had intended to say "...one small step for a man," but the indefinite article is definitely missing from the transmission. In 1971, asked by writer Robert Sherrod whether the "a" had been lost in transmission or simply forgotten, Armstrong, clearly savoring the ambiguity, replied, "We'll never know." To this writer, the cadence of Armstrong's words on tape suggests that the "a" was forgotten, not lost.

Emphasis mine except for the timestamp.
I never met him myself (I'm simply too young), but I consistently heard he was a pretty humble guy.  Him not being entirely sure — he intended to say it, he believed he said it, but he might have slightly misspoken — is altogether consistent with everything I've ever heard about him.

All I can say is there's a big hesitation there right between 'for man' and 'giant leap' -- "one small step for man... one... giant leap" that, to me, reads very clearly as "CRAP did I flub the line?! Never mind, can't go back, gotta finish it."

I recall someone doing an analysis of the recording and coming to the conclusion that he did say 'a' but that it wasn't transmitted for some technical reason.  There was a dead spot in the audio or something like that. I wish I knew where or had a reference but I thought it was settled that he did say it.

I found something about it but details are light. An Australian named Peter Shannon Ford claims he found evidence for the 'a' being spoken.

Clearly Armstrong was no orator.  The intent of the author was probably to emphasize the "a" strongly.  But in conversational English, in most dialects, it would be hard to know whether the a was present or not without intentional emphasis.  And that's before sending it over a crackling lo-fi radio link.

@DougWarren it's possible...just possible...he had other stuff on his mind other than making a cool speech.

Neil Armstrong wasn't an orator, but as an aviator and test pilot, radio communication skills are critical. There's a technical aviation speak that minimizes unnecessary words, suffixes, and vowels. For example, Apollo 13 had a MN BUS B UNDERVOLT or you're flying in your A320 and see CTR TK FEEDG. I think the accidental missing "a" is a result of this habit and mindset.

The comments of this answer aren't a place to discuss why/if Neil misspoke.  Please move it to chat instead

@user721108 no, I think that's a separate question that could be asked and answered on the relevant StackExchange

There's a three foot drop at the bottom of the ladder, and I read that the Apollo 12 guy said, "Damn, that may have been a small step for Neil..."

@MissUnderstands the actual quote seems to be "115:22:16 Conrad: (As he lands) Whoopie! Man, that may have been a small one for Neil, but that's a long one for me. (Pause)" per https://www.nasa.gov/history/alsj/a12/a12.eva1prelim.html and recordings such as https://youtu.be/E_ZxgzENjlE not sure what source you read that got it so wrong
